# How to switch between VCS Roots in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity

In **Version Control Settings** tab I can add multiple **VCS Roots**. But how can I specify which one to use?

For example I configured two VCS Roots - **A** and **B**.

In the first build step I want to deploy code from **A** and in the second build step I want to deploy code from **B**.

When I am editing Maven Build Step I don't see any options how to choose between VCS Roots.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that this is how they work. When you add two VCS roots the code from both roots will be checked out. You can then just access the code as it was checked out. So build step A can just use the code from one root and step B from the other root.

If you want the code from each root to be placed in a separate folder then you can edit the checkout rules for the roots in that project to do something like this:

```
+:. => RootA
```

so that the code is checked out to a sub folder of the root checkout directory called `RootA`

You could do something similar for the other root so the code for both roots was in separate folders, otherwise both will just be checked out to the root checkout directory

Example:

RootA vcs contains this code structure

```
SomeFolder
    SomeSubFolder
        pom.xml
AnotherFolder
```

RootB vcs contains this structure

```
SomeOtherFolder
    pom.xml
```

When you have a project which has both vcs A and B TeamCity will checkout this:

```
RootCheckoutDir
    SomeFolder
        SomeSubFolder
            pom.xml
    AnotherFolder
    SomeOtherFolder
        pom.xml
```

So in your build step you have to provide step A with the path

```
RootCheckoutDir\SomeFolder\SomeSubFolder\pom.xml
```

and in your other step provide this path

```
RootCheckoutDir\SomeOtherFolder\pom.xml
```

Comment: But how can I tell build step A to use code from one root and tell build step B to use from other root?
How can I do this in Maven Build Step?

Comment: if Step A is a compile step just tell it to compile the code from the path which was checked out from the RootA vcs

Comment: But how can I tell Maven Build Step to use pom.xml from Root A?

Comment: OK. Now It became clearer for me.
But what if I've got such structures of repositories:

Repo 1:
/root/pom.xml
Repo 2:
/root/pom.xml

It turns out that there will be two pom.xml in one single directory. How to work with this? Is it possible to tell root A checkout in one directory and root B in other directory?

Comment: yes, see  near the top of the answer. for each root you need to configure the checkout rules to tell Teamcity to check the code out to a subfolder, like this: `+:. => RootA`

Comment: Thank you! It helped me!